# Expectation of Poisson integral for random integrand

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $N$ be the Poisson random measure associated to a Levy process $X$, with intensity $\nu$. Furthermore, let $A$ be bounded from below and $f \in L^1(A,\nu)$ be measurable. It is well known that

\begin{align}
E \Big[ \int_A f(y) N(dy,t) \Big] = t\int_A f(y) \nu(dy).
\end{align}

I need a similar result for functions on the form $f(X_t,y)$. In particular, I need

\begin{align}
E \Big[ \int_A f(X_t,y) N(dy,t) \Big] = t\int_A E[f(X_t,y)] \nu(dy),
\end{align}

where $f(X_t,\cdot) \in L^1(A,\nu)$. Any ideas as to where I can find such a result, or a way to prove it? Additional assumptions may be put on $X$ and $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g$ be a predictable function such that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \!\! \int |g(s,y)| \, \nu(dy) \, ds \right)<\infty,$$

then one can show that the integral

$$\int_0^t \!\! \int g(s,y) \, N(dy,ds)$$

is well-defined and

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \!\! \int g(s,y) \, N(dy,ds) \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \!\! \int g(s,y) \, \nu(dy) \, ds \right).$$

Applying this for $g(s,y) := f(X_s,y) 1_A(y)$ yields

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \! \! \int_A f(X_s,y) \, N(dy,ds) \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \int_A f(X_s,y) \, \nu(dy) \, ds \right).$$

(I hope that's what you meant; or do you really want to fix $t$ and consider $g(s,y) := f(X_t,y) 1_A(y)$? This works also fine, but you have to be careful about the proper measurability of $g$.)

A standard reference is e.g.

*Watanabe/Ikeda: Stochastic Differential Equations and Diffusion Processes*, North-Holland.

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much :)